# Vuejs - npm version patch - git working directory not clean

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, npm, package

I followed along a guide to learn about how to publish packages to NpmJS. But when I updated the `README.MD` and try to update the package on NpmJS I get the following error:

```
npm version patch
npm ERR! Git working directory not clean.
npm ERR! A  .gitignore
npm ERR! AM README.md
npm ERR! A  babel.config.js
npm ERR! AM package-lock.json
npm ERR! AM package.json
npm ERR! AD public/favicon.ico
npm ERR! AD public/index.html
npm ERR! AD src/App.vue
npm ERR! AD src/assets/logo.png
npm ERR! AD src/components/HelloWorld.vue
npm ERR! AD src/main.js
```

And what I dont understand is that there is no `HelloWorld.vue` in my package. I haven't even used git for this, only npm.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should commit the changes then patch the version :

```
git add .
git commit -m "publish to npm"
npm version patch
```

Comment: Ohman, didn't know git was a part of this npm stuff.. Thanks!

Comment: because the readme file and the package.json and built files need to be committed before publishing them